# How to "escape" a plain list / cannot outdent region

Tags: org-mode, indentation

This is start from:

```
* Up
** Foo
   - x
```

Notice that the plain list under Foo is indented. This is what I want next:

```
* Up
** Foo
   - x
** Bar
```

But from `- x`, I don't know how to "escape" the plain list, in other words start a new headline. In more detail:

1:

```
* Up
** Foo
- x
```

2: Then, `C-x h C-M-\`:

```
* Up
** Foo
   - x
```

3: Then `M-RET`:

```
* Up
** Foo
   - x
   -
```

4: Then `M-RIGHT`:

```
* Up
** Foo
   - x
   -
```

"Cannot outdent top level regions"

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Are you trying to turn the list item into a headline?

Comment: No. In the example shown I am in a plain list that is indented and nested in a headline. I want to start a new headline. I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understand correctly, but it seems to me you need `C-RET` (`org-insert-heading-respect-content`). This should create a new heading even though you are currently inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a plain list, type `RET`, then `*`, then `space`. It's the last step I was missing. Then indent the headline as needed with `M-RIGHT`.

Comment: I wouldn't call this indent.  The doc says "Demote current heading by one level."